Data Factory Unable To Read .xlsx File From Blob Storage
we are trying to set up an azure data factory pipeline to read data from a .xlsx file with about 30 sheets, and then pass that data into a Snowflake table.
The issue we are having is, we can connect to the blob storage that has the .xlsx file in, but when selecting the file it returns the following error:
Only '.xls' and '.xlsx' format is supported in reading excel file while error is '   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at NPOI.SS.Util.SimpleDateFormat.ParseObject(String source, Int32 pos)
   at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.OPC.Internal.PackagePropertiesPart.SetDateValue(String s)
   at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.OPC.Internal.PackagePropertiesPart.SetCreatedProperty(String created)
   at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.OPC.Internal.Unmarshallers.PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.Unmarshall(UnmarshallContext context, Stream in1)
   at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.OPC.OPCPackage.GetParts()
   at NPOI.OpenXml4Net.OPC.OPCPackage.Open(Stream in1)
   at NPOI.Util.PackageHelper.Open(Stream is1)
   at NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook..ctor(Stream is1)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.ExcelUtility.GetExcelWorkbook(String fileExtension, TransferStream stream)'.
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

We have not asked it to define anything as datetime, and it fails to read the .xlsx properly to determine sheet names etc. One of the sheets that we want to import only has 3 rows and 5 columns on for example, so it seems like its getting stuck on reading the .xlsx file overall when we dont need every sheet.
Has anyone come across this issue and a way to fix it? We can't amend the .xlsx file as its provided from a third party source via blob storage. We want to be able to read it and process the data within it into a snowflake table that has been set up to accept the data. That part has worked manually, its just ADF struggling to read the .xlsx file.
I have tried defining the sheet name in the ADF connection but it still fails. I have tried defining the sheet number in the ADF connection but it fails. It seems like no matter what we do, ADF cant read this .xlsx file despite it should be able to. I am able to open the file locally and theres no issues with the data.
Any helps or pointers would be great!
It seems there is a single sheet in the file that has a string in the format of DDMMMYYYY:HH:MM:SS that I believe ADF is trying to read as a date but failing, despite not asking it to try to read it. Is there a way to have ADF ignore this data? Even defining the sheet names fails as below.
Attached is a picture of our blob storage connection in ADF showing connection to the file that is .xlsx

This is the file name, its format is AAA_AAA_Changes_YYYY-MM-DD_YYYY-MM-DD_Relational.xlsx


Could you please provide your blob storage file path screenshot?

Hi @Bhavani thank you, have updated with an image of the blob storage file path.

could you please provide full file name? are you getting .xlsx extension for the file name as this in blob storage?

Hi @Bhavani I have updated to include the file name where I can, including its format. In the blob storage the name is the same as the screenshot

I was able to select the sheet of mentioned format file as this.

Hi @Bhavani yes that is the expectation, however in the screenshots above you can see that if fails to identify the sheet names possible within the .xlsx file, returning me the error I posted


As the excel sheet provided from a third-party source via blob storage, it may in different format even it has.xlsx extension. That may be the reason to get above error. Once download the file to local environment, check the properties of the file. You won't get the error while loading the sheets, if the file in excel format with .xlsx and .xls extension as shown below:

For more information you can refer to the MS document.

Hi there, thanks. The file is a standard .xlsx file, when opening locally it is confirmed a standard .xlsx file with no issues.
